# Install Windows7 on drive with Ubuntu 12.04 already on. Is my plan good?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, mbr

I have Ubuntu 12.04 working fine, but need Windows occasionally. I just wanted to check that my plan for installing would work? Any help appreciated.

Current partitions are:

```
Partition....@ File System @ Mount Point @ Size.....@ Used.....@ Flags
/dev/sda1....@ ext4........@ /ext4a......@ 37 GiB...@ 776 MiB..@ boot
/dev/sda2....@ extended....@.............@ 122 GiB..@ -........@
./dev/sda5...@ ext4........@ / ..........@ 37 GiB...@ 6 GiB....@
.unallocated @ unallocated @.............@ 7 GiB....@ - ...... @ 
./dev/sda6 ..@ ext4........@ /home.......@ 77 GiB...@ 32 GiB...@
.unallocated @ unallocated @.............@ 65 GiB...@ - .......@ 
/dev/sda3...@ linux-swap..@.............@ 7 GiB....@ - .......@
```

My plan is to:

- boot to ubuntu from USB ISO
- change sda1 to NTFS
- install Windows 7 to sda1
- use the "Master Boot Record repair" utility to configure dual boot so I can see my original ubuntu installation as well as W7.

Have I missed something?

I'm concerned as to what the 776MB is that will be overwritten by the change to NTFS. It seems large for just the MBR?

Would also appreciate it if anyone can explain what sda5 and 6 are being used for? Is sda5 Ubuntu and sda6 my data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows will overwrite just the MBR. While it is a small amount of data, it is important, as if Windows has control of it, Grub will not load and you will be forced to boot into Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work just fine. If you want to see what the 776MB are, take a look into the folder `/ext4a` using nautilus or a terminal. Because it is mounted it will have an entry in the file `/etc/fstab`. Edit it and delete the entry for `/dev/sda1` respectively `/ext4a`.

You are also right about `sda5` and `sda6`. `sda5` is the root mount point `/`. That means everything that has no different mountpoint is saved on that partition. In this case your system and your installed programs. `sda6` contains the home folders. Your home folder is used for saving your personal files including the Pictures, Music, Documents, etc folders and even the Desktop. Most programs you use also save their settings in your homefolder. So if you want to reinstall your Ubuntu at some time, you should be able to format `sda5` and use `sda6` as `/home` mountpoint again without formating and all your files and program settings will be kept.

Comment: Windows will overwrite just the MBR. While it is a small amount of data, it is important, as if Windows has control of it, Grub will not load and you will be forced to boot into Windows.

Comment: Yes it does. But you can fix grub using a live cd. This way you can dual boot with grub again even if you installed Windows after Ubuntu. I've done this a few times myself and never had any problems.

Comment: Oops, forgot last sentence. While you can do that, it is more difficult and was not mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Just assumed thats what John F meant by "Master Boot Record repair". You are right, I should have included that in my answer in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @stonedsquirrel and ObsessiveFOSS for your helpful comments. I spent ages (unsucessfully) trying to find a way to see what's in the partition in Nautilus, looking for sda1. Thanks for pointing out to look for ext4a, which I can see under File System, but this just contains a "Lost & Found" folder (which I can't see into), and appears to be only 16.4 Kb, which does seem more reasonable for the MBR. As for repairing the MBR (or should I say Grub), I was referring to a repair utility I found off the internet, but are you saying it can be done from a LiveCD, which sounds safer to me?

Comment: @JohnF You can use the live CD for a repair, and lost+found does not contain the MBR. It contains files recovered from a filesystem check, most likely due to EXT2/3/4 corruption. You can use `sudo nautilus` from a terminal to see these files, but the names may not be meaningful.

Comment: Thanks @ObsessiveFoss. Nautilus from terminal showed no content, so Lost & Found, if only 16Kb, is probably empty. So the invisible 776 MiB used is still a mystery, but looks like it's not user data, anyway.

Comment: The 776 MB is fine, and won't be destroyed via a Windows installation.

Comment: Well, I have to reformat from ext4 to NTFS, so I believe I will lose whatever is on there, but you can't make an omelette without breaking eggs, right?

Comment: If you are talking about `sda1` you'll be alright. We already found out it's only the lost+found folder. I almost forgot: If take a look into you `/etc/fstab` file and delete the mount. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, #stonedsquirrel, I was talking about reformatting sda1. Still puzzled why Gparted shows 776 MiB used, but Nautilus shows 16Kb. Maybe it's just an artifact. Not sure why you want me to delete the mount (presumably of sda1)? As this is the boot partition, that would result in an unbootable drive? I'll have to unmount that partition before I reformat to NTFS, but after I've booted from a Live CD?

Comment: The partition with the boot flag doesn't have to be mounted to be able to boot. It's a flag for the BIOS that the bootloader is installed on that partition. But if it's listed in the fstab as ext4 filesystem you will get mount errors after the reformat.

Comment: Aaaah! Good spot. Though wouldn't Gparted update fstab?

Comment: I think it does. But the Windows installer wouldn't if you used that for formating ;-)

Comment: Got you. Hadn't considered that option. Will let you know how I get on.